# When will Successor be created?

Tags: mongodb

Sitecore Experience Platform 8.1 rev. 160519.

I add a custom processor to the RenderLayout Pipeline to identify contacts.

```
Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(ContextUserName);
```

`ContextUserName` adds a custom processor to the `userResolver` Pipeline and gets it from the email address of `SAMLToken` of Active Directory Federation Service.

Several users have a `Successor` field when checking contact data.

If you are identifying with the same `ContextUserName`, you can not make new contacts, so I do not think that you can do `Successor` data.

Why will `Successor` be created by accessing the site with the same `ContextUserName`?

When several people access the site from the same PC? Or when you accessed the site from multiple PCs? Or is it another case?

Answer (score 1):

`Successor` field is added during [contact merge](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/merge-contacts.html) operation. Contact merge is started when initially anonymous website visitor becomes identified. In that case the old contact get `Successor` set to the id of the new contact which will be used from now on. You can read more [contact identification](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/identifying-contacts.html) process.
If you don't want contacts to contain Successor field, I would ensure that `Identify` is called in all sessions, ie. no anonymous contacts are saved.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
It was very helpful.

Comment: @m.kawasaki, no problem. I would appreciate if you could accept the answer, if it really helped you.